# Is there a GUI for adding deb sources to the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ folder?

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-sources, synaptic

When I add a deb source in Synaptic, it gets appended to `/etc/apt/sources.list` rather than added as a new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. (It also retrieves the public key for the source.)

Is there a Synaptic option or another GUI that uses the `source.list.d` folder instead?

Comment: The default Software & Updates application can edit sources.list.d, but will create new entries also in sources.list. I believe sources.list.d is mostly intended for scripting, any specific reason why you prefer to put your own custom deb sources there?